# XML file validation in Eclipse RCP application for different customized/different file extensions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have some customized (different file extensions than the conventional .xml files) XML files on my Eclipse RCP application and I need Eclipse to display error markers like it does for .xml files when the format is incorrect (for example if there's no end tag for the beginning tag or if the angle brackets are missing). I can easily set this up manually in Preferences -> Validation -> XML Validator -> Settings -> Add new File Extension Rule for my custom file extensions and after setting up this preference the error markers correctly display for my custom XML files when the format is incorrect but I would like this behavior to apply even though the preferences are not set for different file extensions (something we could setup using .ini file).

When I set the File Extension Rule for my custom file extensions then Eclipse stores this following preference in org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs node -

> vals/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xml/groups=0107include07111contentType128org.eclipse.core.runtime.xmlT111contentType134org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xmlsourceT111contentType134org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xslsourceT111contentType134org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.tldsourceT07fileext03xmlF07fileext06varselF07fileext06vardefF0107exclude05113projectNature134org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.EJBNature113projectNature130org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.EARNature04file08.projectT0104file110.classpathT0104file110.settings/T02

And I tried adding the same entry to my product's .ini file and expected the settings to be read upon the product start and the validation behavior to be applied on my Eclipse RCP product to my custom file extension XML files without explicitly setting the preferences manually.

I looked upon the internet for solutions but got nowhere close, what am I doing wrong here? Are the entries I added to my .ini file correct? How can I enable validation for my custom file extension XML files (XML files with different file extensions)?

Comment: First, does your RCP include the Web Tools XML editors components that actually does this?

Comment: Yes it does and I think that's why the validation worked when I enabled them manually (adding the file extensions in Preferences -> Validation -> XML Validator) but I would like to have the same behavior through defining appropriate settings in my product's .ini file. Sorry if I got your question wrong but what exactly do you mean by Web Tools XML editors components and how do I include them in my RCP?

Comment: I think you need to use  the "plugin_customization.ini" for that - see [this tutorial on preferences](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html#default-preference-values-via-plugin_customization-ini)

Comment: Yes I now have the plugin_customization.ini file and it is registered via the preferenceCustomization property in the plugin.xml file and I added the following entry in the file (next comment) but it did not work

Comment: vals/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xml/groups=0107include07111contentType128org.eclipse.core.runtime.xmlT111contentType134org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xmlsourceT111contentType134org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xslsourceT111contentType134org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.tldsourceT07fileext03xmlF07fileext06varselF07fileext06vardefF0107exclude05113projectNature134org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.EJBNature113projectNature130org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.EARNature04file08.projectT0104file110.classpathT0104file110.settings/T02

Comment: Entries in the plugin_customization.ini must start with the plug-in they belong to `<plugin id>/<setting>=<value>`

Comment: yes but is the value correct like I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: Well it doesn't start with the plug-in id so it can't be right. Looks like the plug-in id is probably `org.eclipse.wst.validation`, I don't know anything about what the rest would be.

Comment: Any idea about what the rest could be? I think there should have been a proper documentation/help notes from Eclipse explaining this but I could not find any information anywhere, any help from you would be very much helpful to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to add filename extensions to the relevant Content Type, via an "extension" element in your own `plugin.xml` file. Then almost every feature meant for XML files will, or should, apply to your own--validators, editors, task tag scanning, etc. The Platform defines one content type for XML files, and the WTP XML plug-ins define another specifically for files that could be considered ill-formed or syntactically broken, the ones that would be unreadable by most production XML parsers. They are `org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml` and `org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.xmlsource`, respectively. The Validation framework will then automatically consider your files as candidates for the XML Validator.

https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_contenttype_contentTypes.html?cp=2_1_1_9

Comment: Thank you, I added the following (please see my next comment) in my plugin.xml file after going through the details in the link provided by you but id did not work, am I missing something here?

Comment: <extension point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
    <content-type id="com.bosch.sharccgen93.branding.csttype"
                  base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
                  file-extensions="cst"
                  name="cst">
                  <describer class="org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.XMLRootElementContentDescriber2">
        <parameter name="element" value="cst"/>
       </describer>
    </content-type>
   </extension>

Comment: This would require the document have a "cst" element at its root. I was referring to the `file-associations` element, which lets you add new filename extensions to the existing content type, not `content-type`, which creates your own content type.

Comment: Thank you, so the following entry (please see next comment) in plugin.xml file would be ideal and the Validation framework should consider my custom extension (cst) XML files as candidates for the XML validator right?

Comment: <extension point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes"> 
      <file-association 
       content-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.text"
       file-extensions="cst"/>
   </extension>

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work as well, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you're testing in a runtime workbench using an Eclipse Application launcher, you need to set the configuration space to be cleared for plugin.xml changes to be considered. The content type org.eclipse.core.runtime.text is for generic text files, though, not XML files specifically. You would need to use org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml as in the original answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work too, I added the correct entry (org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml) in the plugin.xml file and also set the configuration space to be cleared and launched my product multiple times and for some reason the XML validation did not work for my custom file extension XML files, any other way to do this or any way to debug the validation framework?

Comment: What, exactly, did you add? The project you're testing these changes with has the XML Validator enabled, and the Validation builder added to it?

Comment: I added this following entry - <extension point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes"> <file-association content-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml" file-extensions="cst"/> </extension> to my plugin.xml file

Comment: This is a real-time project and how do I verify if the XML Validator is enabled and how do I add Validation builder to it? Sorry if I'm asking too many questions since I'm not well versed with XML Validators and Validation builder.

Comment: The `.project` file should have the `org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder` builder installed for the Validation framework to apply to that project, when the project is built.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in response, do you mean I should add this following entry in my .project file: <buildCommand>
         <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
         <arguments>
         </arguments>
          </buildCommand>

Comment: Is there anything else to check for apart from adding the above mentioned  org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder entry in the .project file?

Comment: Those are the only things I would think of as needed.

Comment: should the file extensions be added to Project->Properties->Validation->XML Validator->Add Rule->File extension as well? I tried this too and for some reason Eclipse Validation framework still doesn't validate my XML files and I'm currently out of ideas

Comment: This approach actually worked for one of my custom file extensions (cst) which is an XML file but did not work for other file extension (wer) which is also an XML file, are there any specific criteria for the Eclipse validation framework to consider my XML files for validation?

Comment: Any differences between what you did for the two extensions?

Comment: I debugged and figured out that for one of my file extensions (where the validation is not being applied) Eclipse API org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.DisabledValidatorManager#_map has XML Validator and hence no further processing is being done for this file and the validation does not apply at all, not sure why, any idea?

Comment: Is there a setting on the project or preference page for Validation in your testing workspace where it is disabled?

Comment: I actually have my own content type defined now and my document has cst as the root element and I have this in my plugin.xml file - <extension point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes"> <content-type id="com.bosch.sharccgen93.branding.csttype" base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml" file-extensions="cst" name="cst"> <describer class="org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.XMLRootElementContentDescriber2"> <parameter name="element" value="cst"/> </describer> </content-type> </extension> but how do I make the Eclipse validation to be applied to my CST files which is basically an XML file?